# Python stops working while trying to open Spyder or Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, anaconda, spyder

I used to compile on Spyder at work, so I downloaded Anaconda 4.2 with Python 3.5 64bit for installing it on my own PC too.

But it doesn't work!

Every time I try to open spyder or a Notebook, or even the Anaconda Navigator, it crashes and an error message of "Python stop working" 
I tried to open spyder from command prompt too, to no avail.

On the other hand, if I open a Python shell from Windows Command Prompt, it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, sorry,you are right! I got confused with 2.7 .. I installed python 3.5

Comment: Did you install Anaconda for all users in your PC or just for your current user?

Comment: I installed it in my current user... tried to uninstall and install it again but nothing changes... I think my Windows 10 made an upload few times ago and maybe this is the problem...or maybe does it support only 32 bit and not 64?

Comment: If you're on Windows 10, you could be suffering from this issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3843

Comment: if I launch spyder from command prompt, no error on command prompt is printed, but the program crashes before it starts...so I don't think it's a problem of fonts...

Comment: What errors are you able to see in the command prompt if you launch Spyder with this command `spyder --show-console`?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us the exact and complete error message that you got. But you should probably uninstall Anaconda and all its parts (including Python), delete the `.anaconda` and related sub-folders in your Users folder, then reinstall Anaconda. If that doesn't work, let us know. Don't skip deleting those sub-folders: I solved one of my problems by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall (try disabling it temporarily). That turned out to be the issue in my case (after trying to reinstall different versions of spyder/anaconda 20 times).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command `conda update --all` on Ananconda Prompt to solve this issue. In my case, it ended up downgrading Spyder from 4.0.1 to 3.3.5 (2 versions behind). If the version does not matter much to you, this will fix the error.